# As validate the image path dynamically in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I was able to generate URLs by including codes for a catalog I have validated the number of characters and numbers that should be put into the textarea.

I would somehow validate the generated URLs are valid otherwise show something like "url does not work"

**JQUERY:**

```
$('#enter').keyup(function () {
    var eachLine = $(this).val().split('\n');
    var result = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < eachLine.length; i++) {
        var url = 'http://67.227.171.193/~raulvalv/code/replace/gallery/' + eachLine[i] + '_2.jpg';
        var img = '<img alt="" src="' + url + '" /><br />';
        var empty = '<div class="found">Error code</div><br />';
        if (eachLine[i].match(/^[0-9]{10}$/)) {
            result = result + img + '\n';
            //
        } else {
            result = result + empty + '\n';
        }
    }
    $('#hide').show();
    $('#result').html(result);
});

$('.reset').on('click', function () {
    $('#enter').trigger('keyup');
    $('#hide').hide();
});

$('#search').on('click', function () {
    $('#enter').trigger('keyup');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>

<h3>Enter:</h3>

    <textarea value="" id="enter"></textarea>
    <br />
    <button id="search" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    <div id="hide">
         <h3>Result:</h3>

        <div id="result"></div>
        <br />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button reset" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Sample code to enter in textarea:

```
9998524561
9991239872
9999517533
9994561234
9994561235
```

The last code results in a nonexistent URL, should show some message.

Any idea to validate the url and display a message that the url does not exist?

**JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/5ynfedgo/1/

Comment: I think you should use a 404 page

Comment: Uhmn .. I see that rare either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a nice reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/92819/819651

[integration with your code.](http://jsbin.com/fubeludode/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó el código.